# How do I make a default syntax by filetype in Atom text editor?

Tags: atom-editor

I want my .ejs files to have html syntax, however, it always opens the files as Plain Text.

In sublime you can choose "Open all with current extension as..." then choose your syntax.

[image: sublime text3 syntax]

I see that you can change the syntax in the left bottom corner[image: syntax change]

How do you open files with a certain type with a specific syntax?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Easy mode: include

If your language really is just HTML, you can set up a simple package to handle this.

Create a package called `langugage-ejs` and in `grammars/ejs.cson` you can include HTML as having the patterns you care about:

```
'fileTypes': [
  'ejs'
]

'name': 'Embedded JavaScript'

'patterns': [
  {
    'include': 'source.html'
  }
]

'scopeName': 'source.ejs'
```

[language-ipynb](https://github.com/rgbkrk/language-ipynb) certainly does this by extending JSON.

## What about my template tags?

In reality though, you have template tags on top of HTML that you would want to make the editor recognize. The best example I can find is for [erb (Embedded Ruby templates)](https://github.com/atom/language-ruby-on-rails/blob/master/grammars/html%20(rails).cson). It sources from HTML but also adds on other tags as shown in this snippet:

```
...
'patterns': [
  {
    'begin': '<%+#'
    'captures':
      '0':
        'name': 'punctuation.definition.comment.erb'
    'end': '%>'
    'name': 'comment.block.erb'
  }
  {
    'begin': '<%+(?!>)[-=]?'
    'captures':
      '0':
        'name': 'punctuation.section.embedded.ruby'
    'end': '-?%>'
    'name': 'source.ruby.rails.embedded.html'
    'patterns': [
      {
        'captures':
          '1':
            'name': 'punctuation.definition.comment.ruby'
        'match': '(#).*?(?=-?%>)'
        'name': 'comment.line.number-sign.ruby'
      }
      {
        'include': 'source.ruby.rails'
      }
    ]
  }
  {
    'include': 'text.html.basic'
  }
]
...
```

Comment: `package-generator:generate-language-package` generates a language package skeleton that can then be easily extended.

Answer (score 136):

This is now [in Atom core](https://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/basic-customization/#customizing-language-recognition), you don't need that file-types package any more.

Where I work, we use .phl for a certain kind of PHP file. To tell Atom about this, first [find the language's Scope Name](https://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/basic-customization/#finding-a-languages-scope-name) (e.g. `text.html.php` ), then  edit `config.cson` like so:

```
core:
    customFileTypes:
      "text.html.php": [
        "phl"
      ]
    themes: [
// snip
```

You can find this file at `~/.atom/config.cson`, or from the Settings window click the "Open Config Folder" button.

It's easy to get wrong, as evidenced by the many errors people made on the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/1718) for the feature.

Comment: This should be the top answer.

Comment: Where does the `text.html.php` identifier come from? Is there some reference or way to determine these for other file types?

Comment: The scope name of `text.html.php` comes from grammar list of Atom. You can see how it's pulled in Grammar List package source: https://github.com/atom/grammar-selector/blob/master/lib/grammar-list-view.coffee#L57

You can get a fresh list of grammars from the Atom console (cmd+shift+i or ctrl+shift+i) then paste this:

```atom.grammars.getGrammars().map(function (grammar) { console.log(grammar.scopeName); });```

Comment: Shortcut for Atom console is __cmd+alt+i__

Comment: The documentation links: [Custom Language Recognition](http://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/basic-customization/#_customizing_language_recognition) and [Finding a language’s scope name](http://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/basic-customization/#_finding_the_language_scope_name) are useful

Comment: You can get the current grammar with: `atom.workspace.getActiveTextEditor().getGrammar().scopeName`

Comment: Did not work for me, running Atom 1.13.1 , however found this way that worked well even with extension including a dot, like file.html.eco , see this [link](https://discuss.atom.io/t/edit-set-file-associations/2650/11#post_12)

Comment: Note that for Javascript, it's `source.js`, not `source.javascript`.

Comment: There’s the “Editor: Log Cursor Scope” command to show you what scope the file you’ve opened is in, too.

Answer (score 6):

*Edit:* since the time I wrote this answer, this functionality has been added to Atom core, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32508353/2315334) for details.

#### file-types Atom package

(https://atom.io/packages/file-types)

It does exactly what the title question asks for: you can define new file extensions for existing languages with a simple edit of the `config.cson` file.

Answer (score 6):

For example if you want to open all `.jsx` files with javascript syntax, you need to add this to your `config.cson`

```
"*":
  core:
    customFileTypes:
      "source.js": [
         "jsx"
      ]
```

This maps all .jsx files to open with js syntax.

Answer (score 5):

For individual files you can use the Grammar Selector; <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to set which language you're using on that file. Not the same as auto-detect but useful for those times when you're using a file that you don't want to set a default for.

Comment: Thanks! This was impossible to find in the menu, quite ridiculously so. It never would strike me as Edit -> Select Grammer

Comment: You can also change it by clicking on the current syntax highlighting scheme in bottom right corner (next to encoding scheme).

Answer (score 3):

It looks likes there's a brand new package has been released for this.  https://atom.io/packages/language-ejs.

Comment: Thanks Dan! That wasn't there before. Looks like they're adding packages like gangbusters.  What if I have another weird filetype that doesn't have a package yet?

Comment: "They" in this case is an external developer. You just have to create your own language pack. [langugage-ejs](https://github.com/darron/language-ejs) looks like a direct port of a TextMate Bundle, which you can also create and publish. Sometimes it's as simple as [including another language pack](https://github.com/rgbkrk/language-ipynb/blob/master/grammars/ipynb.cson#L7-L11). Check out [Creating a Package](https://atom.io/docs/v0.71.0/creating-a-package) for more.

Comment: I am using Version 0.120.0 (0.120.0) and I can no longer search for this package anymore.

Answer (score 2):

As Dave Andersen mentions in a buried comment, it is now possible to do this without any extra packages and it's documented [here](http://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/basic-customization/#customizing-language-recognition).

Comment: +1 Simple solution with precise link - reference to finding the Language's Scope Name [here](http://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/basic-customization/#finding-a-languages-scope-name)