# How do I set default syntax highlighting in Atom for Twig files?

Tags: syntax, twig, syntax-highlighting, atom-editor, color-coding

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22363070/how-do-i-make-a-default-syntax-by-filetype-in-atom-text-editor/32508353#32508353), this functionality should be built into Atom, and I should be able to use `customFileTypes` to accomplish this. This is what my config looks like:

```
"*":
    "exception-reporting":
      userId: ""
    welcome:
      showOnStartup: false
   core:
     themes: [
        "atom-light-ui"
        "atom-light-syntax"
     ]
     customFileTypes:
       "source.twig": [
         "html"
     ]
   editor:
     invisibles: {}
     tabLength: 4
     showIndentGuide: true
     showInvisibles: true
```

*Note that I've removed my `userId` value for security, but I do have it in my actual config.*

Oddly enough, if I switch the order of `customFileTypes` with `themes`, my theme breaks. Why is that?

More importantly, how can I set all `.twig` files use HTML (or HTML Mustache?) syntax highlighting?

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for the same thing, to enable the php-twig package to also work for html filetypes while also allowing the html syntax to be rendered. I changed your `source.twig` to `text.html.twig` which seems to be working:

```
"*":
  core:
    customFileTypes:
      "text.html.twig": [
        "html"
      ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I only got Twig support after installing this package: https://atom.io/packages/php-twig